# How do I create a task branch that includes an imported stream that I must work on? (Edited)

Tags: task, branch, perforce

The project I have to work on is imported into the mainline stream. It has the workspace root as its parent. The workspace root also has some build files needed for all projects. I created a task stream of the entire workspace expecting Perforce to "do the right thing" but it did not. Now I have changes for the project that I am working on (the project that is imported from another stream, but is a child of the parent) and I'm at a loss as to how I should approach this since what I did is not working. Perforce will not let me check these files in. I don't think I want to "force" it because I don't believe the imported stream is part of my task branch.

## EDIT

Here is a hypothetical example. Suppose there are two streams, ***ToImport*** and ***MainLine***:

- ***ToImport***

  - ProjectA
  - ProjectB
- ***MainLine***

  - MainProjectA
  - MainProjectB
  - MainProjectC
  - MainProjectD

In my situation, ***ToImport*** is imported into ***MainLine*** (apologies if my terminology is imprecise, this is what we call it at my dev shop.) So, while it is not obvious in p4v that ***ToImport*** is part of ***MainLine*** it is due to the fact that it is imported into ***MainLine***. (***ToImport*** is self-contained and used in multiple other streams.)

Using my workspace configured for ***MainLine*** and performing a fetch, the following shows up on my local drive:

- ***MainLine***

  - MainProjectA
  - MainProjectB
  - ***ToImport***

    - ProjectA
    - ProjectB
  - MainProjectC
  - MainProjectD

This is what shows up if I fetch ***MainLine*** or if I create a task stream of ***MainLine*** and fetch that. It is the task stream of ***MainLine*** where I need to work on ***ToImport*** (add, delete, modify.) Attempting to do this does not work because ***ToImport*** is not actually part of the ***MainLine*** stream nor the ***MainLine*** task stream -- it is imported. I cannot submit files to the ***ToImport*** stream. This makes sense to me, but what I am struggling with is what *is* the best way to work on ***ToImport*** in this situation? I need ***MainLine*** to exercise my changes to ***ToImport*** so it seemed logical to create a task stream of the whole thing. That's clearly the wrong answer.

What is the right answer? In other words, what is the best way to arrange my task branch so I can have all the code and work on the code in the ***ToImport*** stream.

Comment: A stream can't have a workspace as its parent.  Could you include the stream definitions (`Paths`, `Parent`, etc) as part of your question?

Comment: It's also not possible to work on a project that is only available via a standard import (the files will be read-only), so there are many aspects of this problem description that don't make any sense.

Comment: If the purpose of your task branch is to work on the `ToImport` stream, then it should be a child of that stream so it can `share` its files, and `import` from the `MainLine` stream (rather than the other way around as you currently have it).  (There is not a way to `share` from a stream other than the parent.)

Comment: I'll have to see if I can get that to work. Thanks for your help.